# iCloud backup not backing up from photos mac

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite, photos, icloud

I've paid the extra to store my photos in iCloud, I seem to have two libraries and despite trying to change the backup to the larger library it isn't backing up the set of photos I want.  I've tried changing the settings in iCloud in System Settings.
Does this feature work and if so how do I change backup sets?

Comment: Apple support just pursued a disable your third party firewall line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to replace the whole photo set with a new photos library which Apple support talked me through creating.  Then switch the backup set in the preferences of Photos.
I also used Powerphotos to merge the redundant sets to check that I hadn't missed out on any stray shots.